# mSata 32GB is not recognized by Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ahci, msata

So this is odd. I have a 32GB SSD connected into my motherboard through a mSata port.
This device is recognized by the BIOS, but Windows 10 will not list it as one of my drives. When I run the tool **diskpart**, it does not show that disk.
I tried formatting it with Linux, and did not encounter any problem. Linux lets me partition it, and mount it as well. I used it to clear the disk, and reload it, but it would not work under Windows.

Initally, the BIOS is set to run on AHCI. Just out of curiosity, I switched to IDE mode and loaded Windows recovery tools (using IDE I am not able to actually boot into Windows). Then I ran **diskpart** one more time, and it finally showed me the disk. I don't know if the problem is related to that. In Linux, I am able to load it anyway (AHCI/IDE). I am using an USB key to load that system.